# C# How to find the other index if there exists duplicate value (find highest array value and index)?

Tags: c#, arrays

I saw the article : [C# find highest array value and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index)

I have another question is : How to find the other index if there exists duplicate value?

Assume that array is

```
int[] anArray = { 1, 5, 2, 7 , 7 , 3};

int maxValue = anArray.Max();
int maxIndex = anArray.ToList().IndexOf(maxValue);
```

How to find the other index if I use the method in this article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is "how do I find the *other* index" but it should be "how do I find *all* other indexes" because there might be multiple.

```
int[] anArray = { 1, 5, 2, 7, 7, 3 };

int maxValue = anArray.Max();
int maxIndexes =
 anArray
 .Select((x, i) => new { x, i }) //add indexes to sequence
 .Where(x => x == maxValue) //filter on maxValue
 .Select(x => x.i) //only select index
 .ToList(); //ToList is optional
```

If you only want the last one, or you are sure that there is at most one such indexes, just end the query with `.Last()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This answer your question. Use LastIndexOf() will find the last index of the value you specify ;)

This way you will get the last index and the last index of this value:

```
int maxValue = anArray.Max()
int index = anArray.ToList().LastIndexOf(maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to accepted answer of [Get indexes of all matching values from list using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055391/get-indexes-of-all-matching-values-from-list-using-linq)

All of the LINQ methods are carefully designed to only ever iterate the source sequence **once** (when they are iterated once). Therefore we use `Enumerable.Range` expressions from LINQ to **loop**

```
int[] anArray = { 1, 5, 2, 7 , 7 , 3};
int maxValue = anArray.Max();

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, anArray.Count())
 .Where(i => anArray[i] == maxValue)
 .ToList();
```

Extra info : `Enumerable.Range` automatically excludes the highest index, `anArray.Count()`.